# How can I handle Right click of Inline Hyperlink in RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a RichTextBlock with 2 or more hyperlink inline elements, on right click of any of the hyperlink i need to show a flyout with some options(save link , copy link, go to link etc )
How can i achieve this given hyperlink dont have a righttapped event and RTB's rightTapped has no info on which part is clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I handle Right click of Inline Hyperlink in RichTextBlock

`RichTextBlock` only contains `Click` event. So you can't make right tap menu for it, for  your scenario, we suggest you use `HyperlinkButton` and give `ContextFlyout` separately like the following.

```
<Paragraph>
    <InlineUIContainer>
        <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.Hyperlink">
            <HyperlinkButton.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </HyperlinkButton.ContextFlyout>
            a rich text display container that supports
        </HyperlinkButton>
    </InlineUIContainer>
</Paragraph>
```